# Correct FAB position Material Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I need to create a FAB inside a `md-sidenav-container` in my web application.

My code is as follows:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
 <!--sidenav and toolbar...-->
    <div class="content">
        <router-outlet><router-outlet/>
    </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

The content of `router-outlet` is dynamic, the template that will contain the FAB is the next:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <md-card>
        {{item.info}}
    </md-card>
</div>

<button md-fab color="accent" (click)="addItem()">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
</button>
```

The problem that I have is that the FAB doesn't actually float, it scrolls with the page:

[image: Bad FAB]

I've tried to fix the FAB using CSS, but it doesn't work, so I been reading the material angular [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview), specially the part that says that:

> **FABs inside sidenav**
>
> For a sidenav with a FAB (or other floating element), the recommended approach is to place the FAB outside of the scrollable region and absolutely position it.

So, I tried to put my FAB outside the `md-sidenav-container`. Doing this works as I expected

[image: Good FAB]

but with a problem, Since this button is outside my `router-outlet`, it appears in every page, and I need to find a way to hide/show the button between these, as well as perform a different action when is clicked in each of these pages. E.g: I will need to show the button only in pages like `/items, /objects` and hide it in pages like `/items/show/1`.

I've tried with a global boolean, but it doesn't work since the button is loaded in my AppComponent, and the boolean updates takes place in other components.

What can I do?
Try to fix the FAB position using CSS? or try to find another way to show/hide it? How?

**Edit 07/12/17
After 3 days, I found the solution to my problem in [this thread](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/998). In order to have your button only on your desired component, you need to make this:

```
/* Your component.css */
.fab{
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

So, this will not work until you add the following

```
.mat-sidenav-container, .mat-sidenav-content {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Make sure that this is in the component that holds the `md-sidenav-container`.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add this:

```
<button md-fab color="accent" (click)="addItem()">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
</button>
```

Inside your '.content' block. Like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <button md-fab color="accent" (click)="addItem()">
        <md-icon>add</md-icon>
    </button>
    <router-outlet><router-outlet/>
</div>
```

Comment: I already try this, the problem doing this is that I don't need the button in every page. Please read the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. I think that best way to solve your trouble is to create another component for button with `position: fixed` and use it with action sent via @Input decorator (if you need in different actions at different pages, if not - you can do it w/o @Input).

Comment: Sorry for being rude in my first response. I was having a headache with this thing. I actually found a solution. I'm closing the question and posting the answer. Thanks anyway :D